# php missing entries in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables as shown. I want a code that will print 11 cow as the missing entry in the two tables.since catdog has the word dog that is similar.

table 1

```
amount des
    11 catdog
    11 cow
```

table 2

```
amount des
    11 dog
```

Comment: Don't know what you're asking. This is HTML not PHP or mysql.

Comment: @chris85 If something's unclear, don't be afraid to close it. The OP can always have it reopened when they fix it.

Comment: i have edited its clear now

Comment: @frankblint clear to whom?

Comment: I still have no clue what you mean. Why is "11 cow" the missing entry? What is the logic?

Comment: He want query to find missing records in other table by comparing both table (Ex : query with NOT IN or something like that) , that's what i can guess :)

Comment: @Nanne cow is odd in the table 1  as catdog contains dog word.

Comment: So, first problem is find out whether `table1.des` contains a value X. Step 2: get that value X from `Table2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table2
RIGHT JOIN table1 ON table1.des LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.des, '%')
WHERE table2.des IS NULL;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bc4b/2/0)